# Perl internal server error when using Email::valid

Tags: html, perl, validation

I noticed I'm getting *Internal server error 500* when i try to use Email::Valid in my CGI script. I'm a newbie in this, so i'm not able to understand what the problem may be. I'm trying to write a simple form validator using Email::Valid to validate email addresses, but when I try to put the line

```
use Email::Valid;
```

it gives me the error. Here's my complete code:

```
#!C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe

use Email::Valid;
use CGI;


my $query = new CGI;
print $query->header ( );

my $nome = $query->param("Nome");
my $email_address = $query->param("Email");
my $website = $query->param("Website");
my $comments = $query->param("Messaggio");

$nome = filter ( $nome );
unless( Email::Valid->address($email_address) ) {
    $email_address = "Invalid email address";
}
$website = filter ( $website );
$comments = filter ( $comments );


print "Nome: $nome<br>";
print "Email: $email_address<br>";
print "Sito: $website<br>";
print "$comments<br>";

print <<END_HTML;
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Thanks for filling in our form!</body>
</html>
END_HTML


sub filter
{
  my $field = shift;
  $field =~ s/From://gi;
  $field =~ s/To://gi;
  $field =~ s/BCC://gi;
  $field =~ s/CC://gi;
  $field =~ s/Subject://gi;
  $field =~ s/Content-Type://gi;
  $field =~ s/[\0\n\r\|\!\/\<\>\^\$\%\*\&]+/ /g;
  return $field;
}
```

When using this code without the Email::Valid, it works fine!

```
#!C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe

use CGI;


my $query = new CGI;
print $query->header ( );

my $nome = $query->param("Nome");
my $email_address = $query->param("Email");
my $website = $query->param("Website");
my $comments = $query->param("Messaggio");

$nome = filter ( $nome );
$email_address = filter ( $email_address );
$website = filter ( $website );
$comments = filter ( $comments );


print "Nome: $nome<br>";
print "Email: $email_address<br>";
print "Sito: $website<br>";
print "$comments<br>";

print <<END_HTML;
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Thanks for filling in our form!</body>
</html>
END_HTML


sub filter
{
  my $field = shift;
  $field =~ s/From://gi;
  $field =~ s/To://gi;
  $field =~ s/BCC://gi;
  $field =~ s/CC://gi;
  $field =~ s/Subject://gi;
  $field =~ s/Content-Type://gi;
  $field =~ s/[\0\n\r\|\!\/\<\>\^\$\%\*\&]+/ /g;
  return $field;
}
```

Comment: You should always `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your scripts. They will give you helpful error messages. The 500 is displayed because there is a fatal error, but because the program does not send a content-type header first, it's treated like an _internal server error_ by the web server. The HTTP response is broken. That's normal when something goes wrong. You can use https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Carp#REDIRECTING-ERROR-MESSAGES to get the message through to the browser while developing. Maybe you have not installed Email::Valid?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the `Email::Valid` module installed. What happens if you run the program from the command line? Also, you must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program you write

Comment: @Borodin Running the script with strict and warnings gives me the same error. End of script output before headers: contatti.cgi

And about installation of modules, aren't those already installed in xampp? I mean, what happens if i use a module like this in a webserver? Isn't there a standard library like other languages?. Sorry for my dumbness but i'm into perl since a couple of days so i don't know how it works

Comment: Yes Perl has a standard library like other languages. No, `Email::valid` isn't in it. Given that you say you don't know how Perl works, why are you arguing with me about the solution?

Comment: Like @Borodin stated, my first guess was that you probably don't have `Email::Valid` installed. On the command line, what's the output when you run this: `perl -MEmail::Valid`? If you get an error, run `sudo cpan install Email::Valid`.

Comment: Any time you get an HTTP 500 error, check the webserver error logs to see the exact cause.

Comment: If you run your CGI program from the command line as I asked, with `perl contatti.cgi`. I expect that you will get an error message saying `Can't locate Email/Valid.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Email::Valid module)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, i found that the Perl server i was running through XAMPP didn't install the modules successfully. I decided to switch to Strawberry which is running smoothly! So the problem was XAMPP and module installation.

Thanks for the suggestions and for the help to all the people